# Does this headphone jack-type component exist?

Tags: components, headphones

For a personal project, I'm looking for kind of equipment that acts like headphone jack and plug, where the plug can be easily pulled out after applying some force on the wire.

However, the problem with using a headphone jack is that the plug can't be pulled from the wire when is pulled at an angle (unless you pull very hard). Is there any component that can do this? Or is it possible to modify an ordinary headphone jack to do this? 
Please comment if you'd like for me to elaborate. Thanks! :)

**EDIT:** It doesn't have to be a headphone jack styled component. All I'm trying to do is create a wire that can be disconnected (by being pulled) from a circuit, which would result in electricity flowing through a different path. 
However, now that I think about it, a headphone jack is probably not the best way to do this because the jack doesn't necessarily complete a circuit only when the plug is plugged in. So, if there's a better way to do this, please share!

Comment: something magnetic perhaps?

Comment: I thought about that, but unless I use very strong magnets, they would separate too easily. I'm looking to separate them with the force similar to one required for a headphone jack (which is why I used that as the example haha)

Comment: It sounds more like you want a switch that is operated by pulling on a string.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid damaging stuff, use a short cable with a headphone socket one one and and a plug on the other,  when  you pull long cable the socket will furn to face the cable and it will decouple.

eg: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/short-3.5/32810396861.html

Comment: Smart idea! However, I realized that my question wasn't a very good one, so I made an edit to my post. Thanks for sharing.